# R - Plot multiple columns as years on x-axis, plot rows as different lines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, melt, line-plot

Here's my data frame:

```
            2010    2011   2012   2013   2014   2015
 A             0     100    164     75    154    110
 B            71      77    136     58    138    136
 C             0       0    132     53     83      0
```

I'd like to make a line graph in which the years are plotted along the x-axis and and counts are plotted along the y-axis, with rows A, B, and C each having their own line. Is it possible to do this without melting the years into a single variable?

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for this, `matplot`. Try

```
matplot(yourData, type="l")
```